# How to use \r and \n (new line character) with Curl command?

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab, libcurl, gitlab-api

I use following bash script line to update the description of GitLab group which use curl. But it prints in the description

```
Test_1\r\nTest_2\r\nTest3
```

I want this

```
Test_1
Test_2
Test_3
```

Bash script command

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" "$GIT_API/groups/1079?description=Test_1\r\nTest_2\r\nTest3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use C-Style strings that can contain decoded escaped characters like:

`$'Test_1\r\nTest_2\r\nTest3'`

```sh
curl \
  --request PUT \
  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" \
  "$GIT_API/groups/1079?description="$'Test_1\r\nTest_2\r\nTest3'
```

Eventually:

```sh
group_id=1079
group_description=$'Test_1\r\nTest_2\r\nTest3'

curl \
  --request PUT \
  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" \
  "$GIT_API/groups/$group_id?description=$group_description"
```

Comment: This outputs following error: " curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL "